# Why did the last two NASA rovers land in craters?

Tags: landing, rovers, crater

Perseverance landed in Jezero crater, Curiosity in Gale crater. Do craters have any specific properties that make them desirable landing sites for rovers?

Comment: NASA has a site for selecting the Perseverance landing site: https://marsnext.jpl.nasa.gov/ It lists all the scientific and engineering constraints and objectives, and it has all slides for all 4 workshops that were held.

Comment: The Spirit rover landed in Gusev crater.

Comment: I think it has to do with  former lakes in those three craters.

Comment: Something to keep in mind:  A crater is blasted out of the landscape and thus provides access to various geologic layers.  If I wanted to see a bunch of different geology without going too far I would be looking for something that dug down.  The ultimate example on Earth is the Grand Canyon.  Canyons tend to have steep sides, but big craters will be more rover-friendly and a lot more common on Mars than on Earth.

Comment: It also has something to do with just *how much* of Mars' surface is designated as "crater". Just about everything there is either a mountain, canyon, or crater. Technically, the entire northern 40% of the whole planet(North Polar Basin) is one stonking huge crater.